# Search for a common substring

Tags: javascript

The script searches for the largest substring in the array of strings. But if the string does not begin with "A", the search fails.
How to implement a search for substrings inside? ("ABCDE", "XBCDJL") = BCD

```
var array = ["ABCDEFZ", "ABCDXYZ"],
  prefix = array[0],
  len = prefix.length;
for (i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
  for (j=0, len=Math.min(len,array[j].length); j<len; j++) {
    if (prefix[j] != array[i][j]) {
      len = j;
      prefix = prefix.substr(0, len);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: well loop until you find the first match....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

```js
var array = ["ABCDEFZ", "EBCDXYZ"];

/* In case there is a match, it has to exist in the first string as well. 
 * So, irrespective of the length of first string,
 * we will do our iterations w.r.t. its length */
function findLargestSubstr(arr) {
  if(!arr.length) return;
  let length = arr[0].length; // length over the first item in array
  let val; // value that will be returned
  /* looping through the length of first element combinations
   * where the first combination will be the complete string and
   * the second will be 1 less than the length and then so on */
  outer: for (let i = length; i > 0; i--) {
    // For every iteration, create the subset of substring that need to be checked
    for (let j=0; j <= length - i; j++) {
      // Get the substring
      let temp = arr[0].substr(j, i);
      // Check for the substring for every element in the array
      if(arr.every(v => v.includes(temp))) {
        /* If the match is found, then 
         * set the return value to the match and break the loop's */
        val = temp;
        break outer;
      }
    }
  }
  return val;
}

console.log(findLargestSubstr(array));
```

Comment: Since `temp` is by definition a substring of `arr[0]` I'm curious why you need to check that again with: `if(arr.every(v => v.includes(temp)))`? Isn't it enough to check `if(arr[1].includes(temp))`?

Comment: @Mark If there were 2 elements in the array then yes, however, if there are more elements then no.

Comment: @Иван - Did you mean if the array is empty? You can simply add a safe check `if(!arr.length) return;` for that in the function. See the updated answer for the same.